# c# wpf rotate animation for pie slice (drawn using PathGeometry)

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, pathgeometry

Is there anyway for me to have a rotate animation for a PathGeometry that consists of arc and line segments (a pie) from angle A to angle B?

The PathGeometry is drawn using c# instead of xaml, so answers in c# instead of xaml will be appreciated and the animation is required to be played when  it's loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm missing something: can't you just apply `RotateTransform` to `Transform`, and then animate the `Angle` property?  Eg:

```
<Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="5" Width="100" Height="100">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="RotationStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="RotatingState">
                <Storyboard Duration="0:0:1" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True">
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="rotateTransform"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                                     To="45"
                                     />
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <ei:GoToStateAction StateName="RotatingState" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry>
            <PathGeometry.Transform>
                <RotateTransform x:Name="rotateTransform" Angle="0" />
            </PathGeometry.Transform>
            <PathFigure StartPoint="10,10">
                <LineSegment Point="50,0" />
            </PathFigure>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

Comment: Yeah sorry for that, I forgot to mention that the PathGeometry is drawn using c# instead of xaml, it's required. I tried to do similar thing but then it has no render Transform. Or can you repost the answer in c#?